# How to put paragraph under each image when using owl-carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="owl-demo">
        <div class="item"><a href=""><img src="http://ppt.cc/1BbHy" alt="image-03.png"></a><p>123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</p></div>
        <div class="item"><a href=""><img src="http://ppt.cc/1BbHy" alt="image-03.png"></a><p>123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</p></div>
        <div class="item"><a href=""><img src="http://ppt.cc/1BbHy" alt="image-03.png"></a><p>123456789012345678901234567890</p></div>
        <div class="item"><a href=""><img src="http://ppt.cc/1BbHy" alt="image-03.png"></a><p>123456789012345678901234567890</p></div>
        <div class="item"><a href=""><img src="http://ppt.cc/1BbHy" alt="image-03.png"></a><p>123456789012345678901234567890</p></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#owl-demo .item{
margin: 0px 5px 0px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    items : 5,
    itemsDesktop : [1024,5],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
    navigation : true,
    pagination : false,
    navigationText : ["<", ">"]
  });
});
```

I am using owl-carousel for slider and would like to add some text or paragraph under each image.Owl-carousel support responsive for slider so how to put paragraph under each image and also support responsive design?
Here is my code on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/enyLmpby/)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working?! If you didn't have ridiculously long test text it should be fine but otherwise you can add this as a CSS rule `#owl-demo .item p {
  max-width: 150px; /* or whatever you want */ 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}`

Comment: ohohohoh.... my code is really working. I don't know why this happen with that long string without any spaceXD

Comment: A working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/enyLmpby/1/